# MVC 6 Web Api: Resolving the location header on a 201 (Created)

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, dnx

In Web Api 2.2, we could return the location header URL by returning from controller as follows:

```
return Created(new Uri(Url.Link("GetClient", new { id = clientId })), clientReponseModel);
```

`Url.Link(..)` would resolve the resource URL accordingly based on the controller name `GetClient`:

[image: Location header]

In ASP.NET 5 MVC 6's Web Api, `Url` doesn't exist within the framework but the `CreatedResult` constructor does have the location parameter:

```
return new CreatedResult("http://www.myapi.com/api/clients/" + clientId, journeyModel);
```

**How can I resolve this URL this without having to manually supply it, like we did in Web API 2.2?**

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I didn't realise it, but the `CreatedAtAction()` method caters for this:

```
return CreatedAtAction("GetClient", new { id = clientId }, clientReponseModel);
```

Ensure that your controller derives from MVC's Controller.

Comment: You should use nameof(GetClient) to avoid future refactoring bugs.

Answer (score 12):

In the new ASP.NET MVC Core there is a property `Url`, which returns an instance of `IUrlHelper`. You can use it to generate a local URL by using the following:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Post([FromBody] Person person)
{
  _DbContext.People.Add(person);
  await _DbContext.SaveChangesAsync();

  return Created(Url.RouteUrl(person.Id), person.Id);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is an `UrlHelper` class which implements `IUrlHelper` interface.
It provides the requested functionality.

[Source code](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/b5237b29b55e3045e2e3c3f9f10cf72861e3f206/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Core/UrlHelper.cs)

Answer (score 1):

There is also `CreatedAtRoute`:

```cs
public async Task<IActionResult> PostImpl([FromBody] Entity entity)
{
  ...

  return CreatedAtRoute(entity.Id, entity);
  //or
  return CreatedAtRoute(new { id = entity.Id }, entity);      
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My GET action has a route name

```
    [HttpGet("{id:int}", Name = "GetOrganizationGroupByIdRoute")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Get(int id, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
    {
        ...
    }
```

And my POST action uses that route name to return the URL

```
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<HttpStatusCodeResult> Post([FromBody]OrganizationGroupInput input, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
    {
        ...
        var url = Url.RouteUrl("GetOrganizationGroupByIdRoute", new { id = item.Id }, Request.Scheme, Request.Host.ToUriComponent());
        Context.Response.Headers["Location"] = url;
        ...
    }
```

Resulting response using Fiddler
[image]

Hope that helps.

Answer (score -2):

I use this simple approximation based on the Uri being served at the web server:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("")]
public IHttpActionResult AddIntervencion(MyNS.MyType myObject) {
  return Created<MyNS.MyType>(Request.RequestUri + "/" + myObject.key, myObject);
}
```

Comment: You can just do [HttpPost("")]. just a small shortcut i wanted to add.