# Returning the URI of a newly created resource in ASP.NET Core 2.2

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core

I would like to return the location URI of a newly created resource in ASP.NET Core 2.2. Here is the method to get a Food Item for a Food Vendor:

```
[HttpGet("{foodVendorId}/foodItems/{foodItemId}", Name = "GetFoodItem")]
public IActionResult GetFoodVendorFoodItem(int foodVendorId, int foodItemId)
{
    if (!_foodDeliveryAPIRepository.FoodVendorExists(foodVendorId))
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    var foodItem = _foodDeliveryAPIRepository.GetFoodItemForFoodVendor(foodVendorId, foodItemId);

    if (foodItem == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    var foodItemResult = Mapper.Map<FoodItemDto>(foodItem);

    return Ok(foodItemResult);
}
```

And here is the method to add or create a food item for a Food Vendor:

```
[HttpPost("{foodVendorId}/foodItems")]
public IActionResult CreateFoodItem(int foodVendorId, [FromBody] FoodItemForCreationDto foodItem)
{
    if (foodItem == null)
    {
        return BadRequest();
    }

    if (!_foodDeliveryAPIRepository.FoodVendorExists(foodVendorId))
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    var finalFoodItem = Mapper.Map<Entities.FoodItem>(foodItem);

    _foodDeliveryAPIRepository.AddFoodItemForFoodVendor(foodVendorId, finalFoodItem);

    if (!_foodDeliveryAPIRepository.Save())
    {
        return StatusCode(500, "A problem happened while handling your request.");
    }

    var createdFoodItemToReturn = Mapper.Map<Models.FoodItemDto>(finalFoodItem);

    return CreatedAtRoute("GetFoodItem", new
        { foodVendorId = foodVendorId, id = createdFoodItemToReturn.Id }, createdFoodItemToReturn);
}
```

Upon creating the FoodItem, the values gets to the database but it returns a 500 server error after creation. After debugging it, I realize the error is in the return statement of the CreatedAtRoute -

```
return CreatedAtRoute("GetFoodItem", new
        { foodVendorId = foodVendorId, id = createdFoodItemToReturn.Id }, createdFoodItemToReturn);
```

What am I not doing right?
- [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31957060/mvc-6-web-api-resolving-the-location-header-on-a-201-created) didn't solve my problem.

Comment: Check your server logs - That 500 will be due to an exception that will have more details.

Comment: Maybe change `id =` to `foodItemId =` so the property name matches the route parameter name.

Comment: @KirkLarkin, the log says 'System.InvalidOperationException: No route matches the supplied values.' and I've checked it out. It is a known [bug](https://github.com/Microsoft/aspnet-api-versioning/issues/18) from Microsoft in time past, but this has been fixed.

Comment: @madreflection it still doesn't change anything.

Comment: I've updated the question per @madreflection's suggestion and Yes, there is a route parameter on the controller - `[Route("api/foodVendors")]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tried to reproduce your exception and I did. After debugging I noticed that when you return `CreatedAtRoute` you passed **id** as the name of **foodItemId** instead and that's the problem.

Your route parameter **names** should be exactly the same as your GET action input ones.

So here is your simplified code that I used to test:

```
[HttpGet("{foodVendorId}/foodItems/{foodItemId}", Name = "GetFoodItem")]
public IActionResult GetFoodVendorFoodItem(int foodVendorId, int foodItemId)
{
    return Ok(";)");
}

[HttpPost("{foodVendorId}/foodItems")]
public IActionResult CreateFoodItem(int foodVendorId)
{
    return CreatedAtRoute("GetFoodItem", new { foodVendorId, /* this was the problem => */ foodItemId = 5 }, new { result = "Done" });
}
```

Comment: It still doesn't work here's what I'm using... `return CreatedAtRoute("GetFoodItem", new
            { foodVendorId = foodVendorId, id = createdFoodItemToReturn.Id }, createdFoodItemToReturn);`

Comment: @Samseen Replace that with this instead: `return CreatedAtRoute("GetFoodItem", new { foodVendorId, foodItemId = createdFoodItemToReturn.Id }, createdFoodItemToReturn);`